# log4net roll logs every 10 minutes

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, rollingfileappender

I need log4net to roll it's logs every ten minutes.  I don't see how to do this.  Right now, I roll the logs every 1 minute or every one hour.  This isn't sufficent.  I need to be able to configure log rolling by more specific intervals.

I'm told `<datePattern value="MMdd_HHm"/>` (removing that last 'm') won't work.

Can I do with with the log4net config or do I need to create a external program to, for instance, concatenate 10 one minute logs every ten minutes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719546/have-a-log4net-rollingfileappender-set-to-roll-weekly take a look you might will have to change it to minutes

Comment: That looks like what I want, thanks.