# Could Log4net be used to create log files weekly?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am using log4net for logging service in my Outlook Add-In. 
How to configure it for creating one log per week and also I want to delete that log after a complete week.

Comment: why would you want to do that? if the bug occurs an hour (or a minute) before the start of the new week, you lose all your logging.

Comment: My client has told me to do..

Comment: @AnurajSharma you can point this point out to the client. It is important they understand the implications of their requirements. Perhaps propose to keep the logs for two weeks or 1 month before they're deleted.

Comment: Yes I will suggest them..but is there any way to delete logs while using log4net after a month

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can create logs weekly. See how you do it on daily basis in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165084/log4net-rolling-daily-filename-with-date-in-the-file-name). Here is [a possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719546/have-a-log4net-rollingfileappender-set-to-roll-weekly), however it's been 5 years since it was proposed.

Removing can be done with a PowerShell script + Windows job, by service or other means. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date) for possible solutions.